# Handle 403 error for images that are set as background image in a div using Angular

Tags: html, angular

I'm setting the background image for `div`s. I'm not able to trigger the error function whenever a 403 error comes for the image urls. How can I disable the image `div` whenever an error occurs. Could anyone please help?

**HTML**

```
<div *ngIf="imageUrl && !post.imageError" 
     [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + post.imageUrl + ')' }"              
     (error)="handleError(post, $event)">
</div>
```

**TS**

```
  handleError(post, event) {
    console.log('error', event);
    post.imageError = true;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<img>` tag has an error event if the file cant be loaded.  CSS properties don't.

You can make an `http.get` request to get the image, and if that errors you can run your error handler.

```js
this.http.get(post.imageUrl).pipe(catchError(error => this.handleError(post, error)).subscribe();
```

EDIT:  Thinking of another way so you don't have to worry about subscriptions and can use async pipe in your template

```js
getImageForPost(post): Observable<string> {
    // if it doens't fail, it will just return the imageUrl
    //if it errors, it won't return anything 
    this.http.get(post.imageUrl).pipe(map(() => post.imageUrl)
}
```

Template

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="getImageForPost(post) | async as imageUrl;">
<div [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + imageUrl + ')' }"></div>
</ng-container>
```

Pretty sure the browser should cache the image from the `http.get` call as well, so when it sets it to the `background-image` it should pull it from cache.  If it doesn't I guess you could base64 encode the image you get in the http response and pass that to `background-image`